# mysql parition pruning not working with joins

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Partition pruning is not working with join.
Posts table is partitioned by Range of tag_id. Parition pruning was  without join and applying where condition on tag_id field.
Mtom Table is just many to many table storing tags chosen by user.

```
EXPLAIN PARTITIONS SELECT
posts.post_id,
posts.owner_id

FROM `posts_main` AS posts
JOIN `posts_tags_user_mtom` AS mtom
ON posts.tag_id = mtom.tag_id

ORDER BY posts.post_id DESC
LIMIT 50;
```

[Result of query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SY4mo.png)

[Posts table paritions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1usXZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Achieved this by following code:

```
BEGIN
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`tag_id`) INTO @posts_tags FROM posts_tags_user_mtom WHERE `user_id` = 12 AND `active` = 1;

PREPARE stmt FROM CONCAT("EXPLAIN PARTITIONS SELECT posts.post_id,posts.owner_id FROM `posts_main` AS posts WHERE posts.tag_id IN(" ,@posts_tags, ") ORDER BY posts.post_id DESC;");

EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```